# filter a n*n matrix with row number greater than column number efficient

Tags: r, matrix

I have a n*n matrix and want to select these data with row number greater than its column number.

I have tried with a loop in R, the problem is that is too slow.

```
matrix_new <- NULL

for (i in 1:nrow(matrix)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(matrix)) {
    if (i > j) {
      matrix_new <- c(matrix_new, matrix[i,j]) 
    }
  }
}
```

double loop seems very slow in R. Is there are any efficient way to do this?

Comment: What is your expected ouput? a vector of the data points in the *lower triangular matrix*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a base R function for lower triangle matrices:

`m[lower.tri(m, diag = F)]`

Comment: Maybe they are looking for `m[lower.tri(m)]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
n <- 3
mat <- matrix(letters[1:n^2], nrow = n)
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  "d"  "g" 
# [2,] "b"  "e"  "h" 
# [3,] "c"  "f"  "i" 

mat[lower.tri(mat, diag = FALSE)]
# [1] "b" "c" "f"
```

Comment: yes! that is my desired result. Can you explain this "lower.tri" a bit more?

Comment: `lower.tri()` returns a logical matrix where the elements which `i>j` are `TRUE` but `FALSE` otherwise. You can use this matrix to *subset* the original matrix.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a logical condition with `row/col`

```
mat[row(mat) > col(mat)]
```